# Extract part of text with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I extract the text after the "br/" tag? 
I only what that text and not whatever would be inside the "strong"-tag.

```
<p><strong>A title</strong><br/>
Text I want which also
includes linebreaks.</p>
```

Have tried code such as

```
text_content = paragraph.get_text(separator='strong/').strip()
```

But this will also include the text in the "strong" tag.

The "paragraph" variable is a bs4.element.Tag if that was not clear.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `page = soup.find('p').getText()` Something like this.

Comment: I already have the 'p' tag so this will just return None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `<p>` tag, then find the `<br>` within that and use `.next_siblings`

```
import bs4

html = '''<p><strong>A title</strong><br/>
Text I want which also
includes linebreaks.</p>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

paragraph = soup.find('p')
text_wanted = ''.join(paragraph.find('br').next_siblings)

print (text_wanted)
```

**Output:**

```
print (text_wanted)

Text I want which also
includes linebreaks.
```

Answer (score 1):

Find `<br>` tag and use `next_element`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<p><strong>A title</strong><br/>
Text I want which also
includes linebreaks.</p>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
item=soup.find('p').find('br').next_element
print(item)
```

Comment: Million thanks. This works just as well as the solution above!